# JavaScript: Object variable changes

Tags: javascript

```
var y = {a:200,b:{}}; 
console.log(y); 
y.a = 100; 
y.b[1] = 10; 
y.b[2] = 20; 
console.log(y);
```

Both the results on the console are same. Any idea why?

```
Result for line 2 
Object {a: 200, b: Object} a: 100 b: Object 1: 10 2: 20 
Result for Line 6 
Object {a: 100, b: Object} a: 100 b: Object 1: 10 2: 20
```

Comment: The console always shows you the current state of an object, it doesn't capture the state as it was when logged. Put a `debugger;` after the first log to see the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`console.log()` has some funny behaviors in some browsers (I've seen it in Chrome) that probably has to do with the fact that console itself is in a different process and data has to get marshalled across a process boundary in the background (so it isn't done synchronously with your Javascript execution).

It appears that when you do something like `console.log(y);` and `y` is an object, what is immediately stored for the console is a reference to `y` and then sometime slightly later, the actual contents of `y` are fetched and displayed.  But, if in the meantime your Javascript has modified `y`, then you won't necessarily get the exact right value for `y` displayed in the console.

You can work-around this issue by doing this:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(y));
```

And, in fact you can test your code by changing both of your `console.log()` statements to this.

Comment: After writing this answer, I found a [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays) and marked the question as such.

Answer (score 0):

Using console.log prints your object to console via reference, you can log the current state of the object by converting it to JSON as an alternative.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(y));
```